# Using Selenium to make Google Keep list, how do you access new note attributes?

Tags: selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def login():
    #print("Enter email")
    #em = input()
    #print("Enter your pass")
    #passwd = input()
    caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    caps["marionette"] = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://keep.google.com/u/0/")
    email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
    email_phone.send_keys("")
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
    password.send_keys("")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    assert "Google Keep" in driver.title
    if "Google Keep" in driver.title:
        print("Success! you've logged in")
    temp = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "Q0hgme-LgbsSe Q0hgme-Bz112c-LgbsSe RmniWd-rymPhb VIpgJd-LgbsSe")))
    #print("How many items in the list would you like?")
    #entries = int(input())
    temp.click()
    driver.close()

login()
```

A script I'm using to log into a google keep account and then make a list, I can log in successfully but get a time out exception when trying to left click on the list component on the right side of the new note textbox. I'm using the class attribute to search for it but no matter how long I wait(even using time.sleep), it doesn't show up. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the className contains spaces, use xpath instead:

```
temp = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class ='Q0hgme-LgbsSe Q0hgme-Bz112c-LgbsSe RmniWd-rymPhb VIpgJd-LgbsSe']")))
```

This should also work:

```
temp = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label ='New list']")))
```